# How to get Instagram media ID from a photo link

Tags: instagram

There are many answers here based on [this method](http://carrot.is/coding/instagram-ids) to convert big id to the short code. However, the big id (like 2017748900654405613_12103976679) is not included in a photo link.

How can I get the media link

> https://www.instagram.com/p/BwBRj3jgsi8/

FROM the photo link

> https://scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/f97884ced334a94f17080e60a5f99f16/5D2D32E1/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/56563284_333674164009004_273410740597618711_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr3-1.cdninstagram.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't go from the CDN photo link back to the media link.

When an image is uploaded to the instagram CDN, it's assigned a unique ID. The media link is a "post", hence the `/p/`. The post is assigned its own unique ID upon creation, and the linking of the CDN URL as well as other stuff like the user id is stored on Instagram's backend.

These unique IDs aren't related, so you can't use a CDN to get the ID of the post. Sorry!